# Почему webpack выводит ошибки eslint несколько раз?

Tags: javascript, frontend, webpack, eslint

Добавил в конфиге webpack, проверку esLint

```
       {
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.((vue|ts)?)$/,
            exclude: [
                /node_modules/,
                /Js-client\/Common\/Main/,
                /Js-client\/ps-mobile\/components/,
                /Js-client\/manager/,
            ],
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'eslint-loader',
                    options: {
                        extensions: [
                            '.ts',
                            '.mvue',
                        ],
                        emitWarning: true,
                        emitError: false,
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

И всё работает, но почему то ошибки выводятся по нескольку раз. Т.е. одна и та же ошибка еsLint печатается в консоли раз 8-10. Например ошибка

```
31:9   error  'a' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead  prefer-const
  31:10  error  Operator '=' must be spaced                   space-infix-ops
```

Выводится раз 8, хотя допучена она в одном месте в одном файле.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста как можно сделать что бы инфа об ошибке esLint выводилась только один раз?**

Comment: *Из любопытства*: а что это за расширение файла - *.mvue*?

Comment: Да, просто тот же vue, просто немного переименовали.